# Wordpress wplogin is not aviailable after copying installation

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, migration, database-migration

First: I know that this question is existing in many variations and that there have been many answers but none of the solutions worked for me.

I have a working instance of WP running on my server, but I want to work on a new design and parallel run the old site. So I created a new subfolder `neu` on my server and copied all the WP-Files I had in this folder. I Also created a new database and imported my old database-file via sql inside the new database. Before I have imported the sql file I used the search/replace function in my editor and replaced `www.myurl.de/` with `www.myurl.de/neu/`. I changed the data in the `wp-config` file and added

```
define('WP_HOME','example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','example.com');
```

to my wp-config.

When I go to the new site i can open the front end sites, but when I try to go to the login page I get a 404.

So I am wondering what else could be the problem. The only thing that I noticed is that when I go to my database with phpMyAdmin and open the `wp_options` table, the siteurl is `www.usersite6.de`, but in the original installation it's the same, so I guess that this won't be the problem.

the site is: http://www.nrc-makler.de or http://www.nrc-makler.de/neu

Comment: Try checking the `.htaccess` file. Probably you have not updated the rewrite rule with respect to the changed directory structure.

Comment: I am not sure, what exactly does the line look like that i have to change?

Comment: In the `.htaccess` file, the RewriteBase reads like `RewriteBase /` then try changing it to, `RewriteBase /nue/`. And the line for RewriteRule should be `RewriteRule . /nue/index.php [L]`

Comment: Make sure you are making the suggested changes in the `.htaccess` file inside the 'nue' directory.

Comment: now I get a "500 Internal Server Error" when I try to acess the nrc-makler.de/neu or nrc-makler.de/neu/wplogin, I don't realy get what I'm doing wrong...EDIT//now i changed once more the siteurl in my database with the new subfolder, and uploaded you htacess, but still: 404 not available

Comment: Can you post the code of your `.htaccess` file in your question? If that is as expected,then at least we can rule out possible problem of .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I decided to create a new subdirectory and do everything from scatch again, because in my try before I did everything just "somehow" "somewhere".
Now it works for me, so here is what I did, if somebody has the same problem.

1. Copied the files to new subfolder
2. created new DB and imported my "old" DB
3. used SQL to update the urls in my new DB

UPDATE wp_options SET option_value = replace(option_value,'old-url','new-url') WHERE option_name = 'home' OR option_name = 'siteurl'; 
UPDATE wp_posts SET post_content = replace(post_content,'old-url','new-url'); 
UPDATE bmccmps7_postmeta
    SET meta_value = replace(meta_value,'old-url','new-url');

4. updated htaccess

   ```
   # BEGIN WordPress
   ```

   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteBase /new-subdirectory/
   RewriteRule ^index.php$ - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
   RewriteRule . /new-subdirectory/index.php [L]
5. added relocate function to my wp-config (right before the "That's all, stopp editing!"-line

   define('RELOCATE',true);
6. Logged in to www.new-url/wp-login with old user data - and it wordked for me